# How to create a new totals (sumif) column in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to create a simple statistic for the kitchen and for that I have a df/table looking like this:

```
meal       ingredient  how_much  in_fridge
ham&eggs   ham         8         6
ham&eggs   egg         24        10
ham&eggs   salt        4         2
salad      cutecumber  16        3  
salad      shrimps     12        4
salad      oil         4         1
...
```

By using the groupby-function,  I can sum up how many ingredients I need and how many I have in fridge for each meal.

```
df.groupby('meal').sum()
```

the result will look like this:

```
meal       how_much  in_fridge
ham&eggs   36        18
salad      32        8
...
```

Now for each meal I want to know the fill-level of ingredients in the fridge by calculating the percentage: `fill_level = in_fridge / how_much * 100`.

The result should look like this:

```
meal       how_much  in_fridge fill_level
ham&eggs   36        18        50
salad      32        8         25
...
```

I also would like to join the percentage in my origin df, so I can see the fill-level of the fridge.

```
meal       ingredient  how_much  in_fridge  fill_level_of_meal_in_fridge_in_%
ham&eggs   ham         8         6          50
ham&eggs   egg         24        10         50 
ham&eggs   salt        4         2          50
salad      cutecumber  16        3          25
salad      shrimps     12        4          25
salad      oil         4         1          25
...
```

How you would code this?
Since I am pretty new in python & pandas I would really appreciate your help.
Best regards!

Comment: if you break down your problem like you have and dig around a bit you could build up a solution and can then ask if you encounter a problem.

Comment: `How you would code this?` Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. `appreciate your help` - [“Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: Pandas has [excellant documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/).

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have a .csv file for your list, this should lead to the output you posted:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv(r'path\kitchen_list.csv', sep=';')
gdf=df.groupby(by=['meal'], as_index=False)['how_much', 'in_fridge'].sum()
gdf['percentage']=gdf['in_fridge']/gdf['how_much']*100
df=pd.merge(df, gdf[['meal','percentage']], right_on='meal', left_on='meal', how='inner')
```

Is this what you were looking for ?